# Scopes and @PostConstruct

Tags: jsf, postconstruct

I'm using JSF 2, PrimeFacces 3.4 and CDI. I've 2 pages: `page1.xhtml` and `page2.xhtml`. Each page has its own managed bean: `Page1Bean` and `Page2Bean`.

`page1.xhtml` has a `<p:remoteCommand>` whose `actionListener` displays `page2.xhtml`.

`page2.xhtml` contains 3 components under `<ui:include>` and one submit button. Each of those 3 components are bound to different managed beans `Component1Bean`, `Component2Bean` and `Component3Bean`. The submit button shows `page1.xhtml`.

Those three `ComponentXBean`s have a `@PostConstruct` method with some initialization code. I tried the following scoped on those beans:

- `@SessionScoped`: everything works fine for single submit operation. When I repeat it, then those beans are not reinitialized by `@PostConstruct` because those are session scoped.
- `@ViewScoped`: the `@PostConstruct` gets called multiple times.
- `@ConversationScoped`: same behavior as `@ViewScoped`.

Why is the `@PostConstruct` called multiple times in view and conversation scope? How can I let them to be called only once per submit operation?

Comment: After I cleaned up the formulation and improved the formatting of the question, I start to believe that you're using `binding` attribute to bind those components with the beans. Is this true? And you're using Mojarra version older than 2.1.18? Then that totally explains the cause of your problem with view scope.

Answer (score 0):

Running your initialization code under 'preRender' every time, is probably not correct. Since initialization will wipe out the data you want.

Separate your `preRender` from your initialization. You can either hook them separately, or have a flag to only call initialize() once.

Avoid Session-scoped beans if possible;  session-scoping is the mark of badly-designed web applications and (in it's simplest forms) a very bad way to implement inter-page flow. Pass URL or POST parameters between web pages to implement flow.

If necessary, the inter-page parameters can be *unique handles* to objects stored in the HttpSession. But don't just dump stuff into the Session without it either being genuinely global to the application (such as "loggedInUser") or referenced by a uniquely-allocated handle.